# How can I find the smallest word in an array for a form application?

Tags: c#

I am making a program that takes in lines of user input and finds the largest word in that list. I have everything set up but that last bit and am not sure where to even start. I think I need to make a function and then call it to display it in a text box.

Comment: Yes. You need to make a function first. Then show it in the fashion you want.

Comment: yes I understand that but im not sure how to make the function XD

Comment: i know. to learn you must try something and share it here. thats how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array, for ex: string[] initArray={"one","twoo","threeeee"};

then

```
public string ReturnSmalles(string[] initArray)
{
return initArray.OrderBy(n => n.Length).FirstOrDefault();
}
```